My new Ubuntu Install isnt working properly
I just installed Ubuntu Server on my old laptop in hope of creating a home server, but ive noticed multiple commands that worked natively on other machines didnt work on this one, requiring and apt install. And when I did that, it gave out errors when fetching from the ubuntu archive website. I figured it was because of internet related issues, but when i checked the network cards (Ethernet) it was disabled, and after enabling it, it would just get disabled after reboot again, and couldnt install the libs still. On my routers configuration website, it says the port is connected (Green) but no hostname is provided. I tried adding the random mac address that was popping up into my reserved DHCP addresses but still trying to ssh that with the networks hostname wouldnt work. If any further info is needed i can provide it.
Edit:
daskey_zits@serverdaskey:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:1c:67:8c:66:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2804:1b3:d001:3a9e:661c:67ff:fe8c:66d9/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 43194sec preferred_lft 43194sec
    inet6 fe80::661c:67ff:fe8c:66d9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:c9:d3:99:e3:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

daskey_zits@serverdaskey:~$ sudo cat etc/netplan/*
[sudo] password for daskey_zits: 
cat: 'etc/netplan/*': No such file or directory

daskey_zits@serverdaskey:~$ sudo /etc/netplan/*
sudo: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml: command not found

daskey_zits@serverdaskey:~$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/*
(A bunch of reminders of this not being kept after reboot I didnt 
bother copying)
# network: {config: disabled}
network: 
    ethernets: {}
    version: 2
    wifis: {}
daskey_zits@serverdaskey:~$

(I put the image through a text recognition AI so some letters must be misplaced with numbers and stuff.)
Images:



Edit your question above to show us your complete netplan (sudo cat /etc/netplan/*) and IP (ip a) output. If you have a network connection, then copy/paste the text directly into your question above. If you don't have a network connection, then make sure any photos are clear and readable.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information. Can you also provide the image you are speaking about?

Just stop your cloud-init by doing:
sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg

Then typing:
network: {config: disabled}

Inside the file and pressing Ctrl+X, then Y, then ENTER to save the file.
After that, do:
sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

And insert inside the file, these configurations:
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp2s0:
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp6: true 

Then, run:
sudo netplan apply

To apply the changes. After all that, reboot to test with:
sudo reboot

And:
ip a

